# Bat file - Hide all messages

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have `@echo off` at the beginning, and `exit` at the end.. The bat adds entry to registry. However, if the registry exists, it gives this message. How to avoid that ? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo y|reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "appdataid" /d %appdata%\data.vbs` if you want to overwrite the existing entry

`echo n|reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "appdataid" /d %appdata%\data.vbs` if you don't

Also, if for some reason you don't want to (or can't) pipe the echo output, you can force reg add to overwrite the value with the `/f` flag, like `reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "appdataid" /d %appdata%\data.vbs /f`